# Google maps autocomplete input personalizado

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, autocompletar

O autococomplete do google maps depois de clicar na rua que quero exemplo abaixo:
[image: ps]

Depois de selecionar a rua ele mostra muita informação.
[image: Imagem com muita informação]

O que eu pertendia era ao clicar a informação ficasse filtrada so queria o nome da rua e o estado. Quero remover os campos 2 4 e 5.

Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Opa José, coloca seu código até o momento para poder ser usado como exemplo para a resposta.